# JavaScriptでif文で処理した値をスコープの外で取り扱うには

Tags: javascript

JavaScriptを勉強しています。
if文で処理した値の取り扱いで躓いているので助けて頂けないでしょうか？
この下記の`value`という値がスコープの外に`return` みたいに返ってくるととても嬉しいです。
どのようにコードを書いたら良いでしょうか？
ご教授お願いします。

```
let test = 10;

if(test == 10) {
    let value = '10です'

} else {
    let value = '10以外です'
}
```

Comment: (単純な分岐条件と戻り値であればですが、) [三項演算子](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) を使用するとかですかね。あとJavaScriptで比較を行う際は [厳密等価](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality) の使用をお勧めします。 例: `test === 10`

Comment: 三項演算子なるものがありました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

上位スコープで変数を宣言すればよいと思います。

```
let test = 10;
let value = null;

if(test == 10) {
    value = '10です';
} else {
    value = '10以外です';
}
```

または、関数にして return するようにしてもいいかもしれません。

```
let test = 10;
let value = ((test) => {
  if(test == 10) {
    return '10です';
  } else {
    return '10以外です';
  }
})(test);
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。とても助かりました。